# jlabels isn't showing the results in the jlabels

Tags: java, plsql, oracle10g

```
try {
  Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
  String sql = "CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_admin(p_username IN varchar2) \n"+
               "RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR \n" +
               "AS \n" +
               "my_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR; \n" +
               "BEGIN \n" +
               "OPEN my_cursor FOR SELECT * FROM login where username=p_username; \n" +
               "RETURN my_cursor; \n" +
               "END; \n";

  stmt.execute(sql);

  CallableStatement cstmt = conn.prepareCall("BEGIN " + "? :=search_admin(?); " + "END; ");
  cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
  cstmt.setString(2, UserText3.getText());
  cstmt.execute();

  rs = (ResultSet) cstmt.getObject(1);

  if(!rs.isBeforeFirst()) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Username");
  }
  else {
    DeleteTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    DeleteTable.setEnabled(false);
  }

  while(rs.next()) {
    NameLabel.setText(rs.getString("name"));
    UsernameLabel.setText(rs.getString("username"));
    PasswordLabel.setText(rs.getString("password"));
  }
} catch(Exception e) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

i want show the username, name, password in the `jlabels` but it is not showing... i have a stored function in database named search_admin. when i execute the program no errors in shown but the `jlabels` don't show up the `resultset` data.

Comment: The following line probably exhausts the ResultSet :  `DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)` , so you have nothing to read anymore .

Comment: what is the solution then?

Answer (score 0):

This line seems to exhaust the ResultSet :

```
DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs)
```

Assuming that it returns an instance of `TableModel`, you could browse its content this way, rather than attempting to read the `ResultSet` again :

```
        for(int i =0;i<model.getRowCount();i++){

            for(int j=0;j<model.getColumnCount();j++){

                System.out.println(model.getValueAt(i, j));
            }
        }
```